# Progress bar from JQuery, is there any way to move it from 0 to 100

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

i was trying to move JQuery default progress bar from 0 to 100%. but i am unable to do it. I used action class, move to element etc. I tried to read style attribute with width 37% and tried to make a change... but i failed... let me mention one thing to you. So you will go directly there or give me other solutions... if you can change style attribute width from 0 to 100% and apply it ... it will work... but i dont have code...

Website url: https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

please give me solutions for default progress bar....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a function called `progressbar()`, It works fine to me. Try this...

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#your-progressbar-id" ).progressbar({
      value: 100
    });
  } );
  </script>
```

For Selenium... First import `Javscript Executer`

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

Then use following code...

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("$( '#your-progressbar-id' ).progressbar({value: 100});");
```

[Execute jQuery/javascript in selenium](http://exploreselenium.com/selenium/run-jquery-in-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: its not working ("<script>
&(){......,

 will you please attached your screenshot. that will be helpful....

Comment: what should i do if i need to display %